# How do I get this rainbow to fade and disappear?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I'm very new to Blender. I had wanted to learn it some day and my young daughter has decided to make a TV show, so I guess that time is now.

I'm using version 2.91 and working in 2D. The rainbow is a Grease Pencil object and the cats are imported images. In this scene, the rainbow is supposed to disappear, leaving the cats to fall down to the ground. I finally managed to work out how to assign opacity values to different keyframes, but instead of fading to transparency, they fade to white and I can't work out why. What am I doing wrong?

[image: The rainbow before it fades out]

[image: The rainbow after it fades out]

Comment: Yay! That's the best reason to lean Blender I ever heard.

Answer (score 0):

Me too a beginner and me also don't know much about 2d animation but I think I figured out how to do it.

After drawing the rainbow chose the frame you want the rainbow to see, then go to object data properties and make sure that opacity is at 1.000 (1). Then move your mouse pointer to the opacity and click 'I' you can see that the opacity tab is now yellow. Then chose the frame that it want to be completely disappear. Make the opacity to 0 and click 'I'. Press space bar and see it fades away.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If I understand you correctly, that's exactly what I did. The opacity property turns yellow whenever the little blue line on the dope sheet is on top of a keyframe. The rainbow fades, but it fades to white instead of transparency. I tried pushing buttons on all the "fill" options I can find, and none of them change anything.